# curl from url and rename to random uuid

Tags: bash, curl

i have the following command to curl a list of urls but I want to rename the output files to something else, as the original name is really long and results in the error below:

command:

```
jq -r '… | .[]' | xargs -I{} curl -O {}
```

error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: 270230751_944073806238863_7984852070388291566_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_n
Warning: c_ht=example.njrsnnkjnrjgngkrnngrggk&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=Ch26T4U5kDIAX
Warning: 8viWsL&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjczOTA2MDk4MDU3MTIyNjQ1N
  0 92492    0     1    0     0      1      0 25:41:32 --:--:-- 25:41:32     1
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1)
```

how to pass some argument to curl so that it renames the file to a smaller name eg 16 digit uuid or something like `njfnjsnf48u8` but not too common as there can be upto 1000 files being downloaded at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the {} variable that xargs uses in curl command to make it more unique. If you are sure that there are no duplicate urls in the input file then the following might work.

```
curl {} -o $(echo {}|base64)
```